# How to Install My Unity to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, show-desktop, myunity

How can I install My Unity to my Ubuntu 14.04? The software center finds nothing when I search "my unity".

Actually I need My Unity to enable "Show Desktop" action on the launcher. If there is an alternative way to do this, please recommend me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My unity has pretty much been replaced by unity-tweak-tool since 12.10 or 13.04.

To install it, use the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Also, CCSM may have some of the features you are looking for. Just select the Unity Plugin from the list of compiz plugins.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

To use CCSM, just use the command

```
ccsm
```

or search for compiz using the unity application search